# Search a string in compressed files in compressed file

Tags: java, unix

I have a compressed file (an EAR), which contains several compressed files (EAR's, WAR's and JAR's), which also may contain compressed files (JAR's.). Is there a way to find a specific string in this structure using UNIX commands without manually decompressing them one by one?

Thank You.

Comment: Not sure how you want to find a "String" or what you mean by it. If a file is compressed, it needs to be uncompressed to read it. There is no plain text method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Java jar executable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) (`jar tf yourEar.ear`), you coud list all contained files in in the EAR in the standard output. 
But **it doesn't list recursively jars**.

So you could :

- chain this result to a grep that specifies the searched string in the filename.
- for each filename ended with `.jar` listed in the output, you could reuse the same logic.